# How to generate pdf for div content for ejs file using jsPDF?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs, jspdf

I am trying to generate PDF file using jsPDF for div content for ejs file.But i am not able to do that.Below are the code i have done to generate it.I am creating a form with Name,email and phone and after submitting it i want to generate the data in pdf formate.Let me know if i am missing something i have already install jsPDF. getting error "jsPDF is not defined" for below code.
app.js

```
app.get('/form1', function (req, res) {
res.render('form', {
title: "Login", 
action: "/form1", 
fields: [
{name:'Name',type:'text',property:'required'},   
{name:'Email',type:'text',property:'required'} 
{name:'Phone No',type:'text',property:'required'}  
]
});
});
```

ejs file :-

```
<div id="content">
<form action="<%= action %>" method="post">
<% if (fields.length) { %>
<% fields.forEach(function(field){ %>
<label><%= field.name %></label>
<input type="<%= field.type %>" name="<%= field.name %>" <% if (field.property) { %>
<%= field.property %> <% } %> >
<% }) %>
<% } %>

<button type="submit"><%= title %></button> 
</form>
</div> 
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>

<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
'#editor': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
}
 };

$('#cmd').click(function () {
doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not included the jsPDF in ejs file the easy way will be adding

before your script in ejs file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).